# undefined reference to `TIFFDefaultStripSize@LIBTIFF_4.0'

Tags: gdal, compile

I am trying for the first time to use gdal in Ubuntu 15.10 with gcc. I call gdal.h in my program. 
At first I got the error "undefined reference to `GDALOpen'", so I check online and I found that I had to link gdal library.
So, now the command line is

```
gcc prova.c -lm -I/usr/include/gdal/ -L/usr/lib -lgdal
```

And the error I get this time is

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpoppler.so.52: undefined reference to TIFFDefaultStripSize@LIBTIFF_4.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpoppler.so.52: undefined reference to TIFFFdOpen@LIBTIFF_4.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpoppler.so.52: undefined reference to TIFFWriteScanline@LIBTIFF_4.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpoppler.so.52: undefined reference to TIFFClose@LIBTIFF_4.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpoppler.so.52: undefined reference to TIFFSetField@LIBTIFF_4.0
```

I am really a newbie in C, I am still learning. 
I was not able to find any solution online, could anyone help me?

Comment: It looks like the geotiff library isn't being found.  Make sure that link against libgeotiff on your system.

Answer (score 0):

In my case libtiff version not updated, I had to reinstall by

```
sudo pacman -S libtiff
```